# how to use JSON Parser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to acces pic field but i am getting like [object object]

here is my data

```
details---------------{"_id":"54c72d2d5d76ab781f3fea08","displayName":"test user","provider":"local","username":"testuser","__v":0,"updated":"2015-01-27T11:45
:00.826Z","mobile":9999999999,"gender":"Female","address":"jsss","designati
on":"","created":"2015-01-27T06:16:13.090Z","role":"authoring","supervisor":[""]
,"email":"xxxxxxx@gmail.com","lastName":"User","firstName":"Test","pic":{"
filetype":"image/jpeg","filename":"747e593f65a3a1122f60f96c67f250c0.jpg","filesi
ze":13000,"base64":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJ
ChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMo
GhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wgARCAC1
AOwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAQUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABAACAwUGBwEI/8QAGgEAAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAECAwQFBv/aAAwDAQACEAMQAAAB8vna4Mj7rGhkvdWh5SDVMTy0+kjCg81BLWO81I4Zx2VzK16p
5zTXk33unIeeLk0hA8gtcwMq/VvFkfNf4GR5J9DcDDp+qyenTlbG0c8XvoQAitXVZm5DTAT5JHXLBxm+
x89RURBMeuKMQWD+y8G19+T0yV2Jrk2eW5lBPXvdByKBP6Lj5R1e+JcE7/wEXTNNldDNENjrlrb+MxS0
sssLRHdoOjcmuFt1IXMU+njZSSU6fZo7SKGdZjGSPpFBuIDP2uOmMIHmSPetguxkZzouPHPJ7lwzufC7
83ouqyYk9Wt5qRn59DfZ0AyOkOnuxFk1sotxXTi+aeaSQlPbaheFnaT6152+qKsM7v2iOeVpLHI9/Gzh
kj0t0AufsnFOv8dr5vekxTZdGUy2hhj2YrMZAWBcVa86hlmk1665li94yvsGP0ae6ENWHkDqZ6ywQnLE
YqGdVp2CNrcryNPQaNbBefpOLdt4nXidDMr7iLzGcLz+fYU+Ge+0hoxwmOMGPQqmPHOC0Opbd9dWNY0x
55MfkTw9TozOzHbLPoxWgVi5OinsHv5p/Tl4c/Fe2cSrLotnXNDmanU+x4UK1dF3EQA+sAiDw4Ch0UtP
DYPZplNdjPiBgOirKOSQ17BylOnoFNPs1xB2zbR8hxEZNZu4l3Hh7ndlh2sVycq18PYDKcRHfBGTHVVf
ia+b04AmUOGaPfnWTJ5s+gYK+qHzeO9tb64racvPzvD5i7yEnMmqYhyIwXGe38Rc9BsArOaz9Fpcnh6o
sla3eLuAmXP1K4Y+K8AZZhFHhdeiL698Nnzg85tg3FNfj3TTCzI6jyYQtqWMQlkbpGC94x2ri4ujXtJp
pM7jdtmMeukFunLsrz3HHPV+WbJzqm2sLKgHTG0H3MhO/NVzyNTGmKrxWyqCaVrAPGI11WeOZkXoS8W7
LxhrpGjzuqkrKu+imskTesm6uc1NBus/Wq+C1iRWT2ErbWTw1IxbCQTHMajL9QeepzPHRtR5MGQz3iPa
OMkusEhJqQJqQJiQP9SBeJA5JAmJBIkgb6kxJIPHpAmJB45IPMykH//EACsQAAICAQMDBAEFAAMAAAAA
AAECAAMRBAUSBhYhEyIxNTIQFBUjQSUzQv/aAAgBAQABBQLYdn0er2xuntvi9PbdO3ttnb+3Tt/bYen9
th2Lbp/B7dF2DbiO39uz2/t8/gNujbDtwn8BoIuwbdD0/t07f26dvbdO3tuh2Dbufb23T+A22DYNuM7f
27Pbu3Tt3bp27t87e26bzQmm3Ppb6X4AbMODM+fiWOIPxx7Qcz4nICerltXqKtHVrOoNTaf3WoZ69Xrd
M239R+a7EsSFTn5hQTIrA+ZmHH6dRfddL/SgGZmZ8zJzaBx/tmX5K64NgzyrJv1teno1mvbcNQayIRF9
6Ok2jcLNuups9atuXL3ZstFSajqDRpO5Ks7fvOl1hIzCpxOovuumPpPiZBn+lv03jVtp12zWHUDXbi6X
6a31qvCjxZOpdULdTxmneOkHseyuMs2Tc/2uocTct9Smai67VWcZiWV5myb2+nYOJnM6j+66Y+l+J7SV
fE5cYvxudfqJpnau1Cz2aAGuknzfd6FGGawrGEpb1K3WJ5qdJqK8l9dqn0wSImB6cKAhqyJcnjpnXG2h
WnUX3XTbY2Tyf0q19FjmsNN8st9RGAT906mvUvhXPE7ula63ear9KhVoELSxMSg8LnEq/wCsyxc2cIiz
ExymIwli5mgt/a7jxE6h+56cH/DkoJrCDpKyvqarX4ltz4xHp92kQiWX31uzF56TCFJXaa5jw4jeYv4C
KuZmuccTAnBgfcxZI6YmoXxpT6ml6i+66dfGz7sHtuTUvpSb8Wp/YfTaw2Dzb/YdPclg1RDH4T8J8xlm
mbEIn+GMZZYbGHGVPwZVwyJPbxK+WEvHIUezS7/9vsH1WsqBUlcWUtmlVFY4hS3Oag8aVHjjiFcTgWNa
+OECn1fQsMK+5mxOWWX8uOQuWf8A3Pg5EOCjzR0+vrOCEb/9vsH0+sy1bj0yq8kABqSvylfjcBilF9pE
KZiImVjriBgreohD3D02tyeYzjkCSJQ/EesuBZ5D5hfBebRpvRrDDHUHneOn/pmwx1NfufULUx1LGDU2
rBr7BLLTqAgwCAIx5TwZRbgtwmoyD60ZvaBmOhEqcoeauLPgXTTZd2wYXLTR6Xma2iDx1D9zsBxs/wDm
66ktcAixeBhrInGVr7VE1APokTy0+SGHpWD2pkwiH3PXiD8gsxBX5pYofU5zTabzUBAFE5hh1B9x04M7
PrcafTrn0iQswGXSv5dCJY4rrYklbjnEKwTiqy0lgntjeJjlPeYq+cRfyzEpawUV8ZSxWLnjxWYBnUH3
HTpxsm9vy21PdWRhq/BAhOZqPllPHiTOPKxaOUAIqyPTNavOIZ3XE4wJBXhAoioXlWlwa14xBK0lXtHJ
RMqJ1D9zsQLbPq6/UoqJU5zK1GLalC/7Yvj4mYp4mpws1TFTU3vwuKVKtYuVHwIviV1ZlSRExFTlPSwK
gcLghkYFCZ1B9xsI/wCKuE1NAXUqlVg91QU+pUrIJqVHMkg+o09R5XhBevOU1ryqQMldZFlycV4+8HI0
tJBFErqxFUCVLiYMwDH9syxCBgOofuen/p7RLlyLSFjWkLyNi+agAzM9ZEI/QP4L5cH+xawTpKcS1RNS
s01fGV1wVRKsxUyV+cgTmCW8z1IXm/nO79PfTWJNQFrDXM51Fbg6dcinkssbNfHxgw1xxgw2MBTX4ryJ
6crpHHhg0jJC+GPEVsbZ/wBa4a5a6wFYASw5VKlCdQ+N56d8bKazjVDkLUCO65FeGCllnyvCFfJr88Mh
tMJbp2m3h20wSWLHAB4clFiVytwyAcyOJhWA5n/pgMDGFnUP3PTf05mqzi+v3f8AoU4JTMFJj14CUkQp
BXxKqTEpDyge1vaET+5vc6AYelrNTab1irq4EtqmNZmqnUVtSGxjDnMzN/8At+mvqCMqVltXk6fLLQBE
qWeiIqeWrMFI4vUpj0YldGJXHfzXYHtKwCEZIrVQucMfEBzPAin3iM83/wC36a+nxmY4z8oyYbjyioAq
4z8QDDODgj31jI4xYygiqsAYh+ATB4jH9Pgen5f2rT4GcQWAnqH7nRbzqdJp+5NbO5NbB1FrBO4tZO4N
XO4NXBv2qE7g1c7h1k7h1k7h1cHUWsA7i1k7i1k7g1cHUWsE7j1s7h1k7i1k7i1k7i1k7h1k7j1s7k1s
fqHWOB1Bq53FrMdw6uavUPqtR//EACcRAAIBBAEDAwUBAAAAAAAAAAECAAMEERIhEBMxICJBFDAyQlFx
/9oACAEDAQE/AfRjqtFmj0nTyPtC3bt9yVLZkUMelvS/aKgYZE7ewlxbae4RQW4ESzJ8x7Mge2EEHB6C
LSZhkSjR7jay4qPaUwgGZt9XRHxKiatrKIQjCxfY0A5lWkGGIlsqeJpDTl7Qx7hDLaj3m1hIshq/zEVN
NllYLpl451pBqZm+pgTI2WUm7iwCVKgWJcbHBhGOlwMoelD8hK1OnWwphq/T4GJWq75MWl7YbQkxaWox
AdGOsa7XWU6gqnE9qcxbgk4YQy/rarp/YYsohm5ENHu8scxLJczTURnIMptkSvlH4+Y7aQP+w8wsai4a
UqbbZYyvcrT/ANlRy52aHoqkUxrKeRzKnAyIGfMPPmKdTLvOQ817vIlO3PzGwnJj3JPCxj0MEtTlBFXm
FlPiZxNv5Hosau0uaXs2lFsPKtcJwPMZy3JhMz0MWWm+OPEDV+/qfE8flGKzbHidzHJjVNptGMz6DBKN
ZkGAYlVdeY1UkYzxMicQ9SfSegM2mZmZm32D6M+jP2P/xAAgEQACAQQCAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAARECEBIg
ITEwQVEi/9oACAECAQE/Ad5J8U+hOzd07ZGWkjcFCTcshUsQ1rBArVOBLPlFUlLFy+bvdFZS4HyJc2nR
2m6KhUHWi26OxD2kyJJtl8FZD7GybsVXBJR8OjsVJFkVHs/OIiCCDEShnZGiGVCqOSGSymt3VouhmJiQ
QQY+SLR4v//EADcQAAEDAQQJAgUDAwUAAAAAAAEAAhEhAxASMQQiMkFRYXGSsTORIEJSgcETI6Fi0fE0
Y3KT4f/aAAgBAQAGPwKztrazLnkn5iN6pYO7yvRd3lek7vK9F3eV6Lu8r0nd5Xou7yvQd3lVsj3leif+
wqlg7vK9F3eV6D+8r0T3lVsnd5XpHvK9F3eV6Lu8r0Xd5UfpO7yvRd3lH9l3eV6Tu8r0nd5Xou7yvSd3
lei7vK9J3eVb2NkIY00H2Vj1d5+GVRSQar8LJUFLoDSja27gwfyURoo/Rs+OblNrb2rpz1l+3pVp9zIQ
Zp7I/wBxn5CD7N4cDkRcDeGn7Kvw6V1/Csqb3efiO6FIy3NVVEKBPFVmifavo1qL9Jp9MfKL43t8XfVY
nNn5CbaWbwWOqIQrvux2r2tbxNFDcdsf6G0X+ktfcIMx4LT6X0+DSuv4Vl1d5Wa4KgooAWVUwWW25Ftt
6m5FujxhbmTWUx4EO3qv3Wzkho1nsWWfN136b8tx4XAql1nYW5/ZtAK/SbjZ6JFpafV8o/usWkPdaHnu
+Buj6a4myNGvPy36V1/CsurvKqoqqAwiUSckHAguaZoUC35VH8ITc94+USi9+0a312hc32ub/wAQho7r
UmzHuRzvpUKb3aNaH9yy2ebVvWldfwrLq7yg72BUvgcV+mx2vzCqV+mHkMA3LKTxUTHELU8IOGJr+LUL
NzXWlqBWE6x2Sd+a1LVhPA0RxU40uHA0uPW43VyUTyWuIPGViF9jabsUO6L/ANWk9R4Vj1d5WuR91aYK
0QLTrTIWCzcQYqU4Wri7LNUz3LWXJYA+hrijcorHBZUuAeSWfyFQyON/3U8LvUapphVaTSuRVAT7LDC2
mozmirJxMEsBWldfwrHq7ym54YoFqHV3tWIACsgLGTTNfKeQKzw7qqmyFU4XDjvQYysDNGM1iYYIPHNT
xrcbI9RcOiAWFYW7O5UBP9WLCt5B4rCHQ05o68N5qNaOSiY4HcoeE7DEKxb82EBaR1HhWM5a3lSs8Tjk
p3Jhc6Jp919XRVrxTzyQupKGKb2lorK4nqq5BYive4TuTQFKrk3gjMxxaETg6OVExnyzLlktI6jwrLq7
yiytVWp4IufxTm/e8oX7QlGN+aoZVMyo3o4sxRbypyUi7FvyChYZW1geFqhk/U27G7bd/CkrSeo8Kx6u
8repRA1jwWqxrR1XyrYYUBhis5qCiTkpNAtU1Qa7JaiDgt6g5mqpdTLgqZ8FTcqrFBpdstb0QtH0G4KK
crtJ6jwrHmXeVVHR7HdtFb3dFvb1vFx6roFv+6B4iVizdlCqq3YTsjdxVIAgyAUPghQ+p3FS/wBlwWIR
KzWk9R4Vj1d5VrazstlYjtPNVu6ko4aOFY5clgdsn+CtZc1rkz0yUPOJjlxjeNyrIbxKbhYDI3rkiYzy
XK6m0oM/DlAWrVGFMLJUWk9R4Vl1d5VvgyhU+UypZK6A3TxVmTlK4EGqiKkzCdhRwvkjkjP+QpOyD7qc
Tp5p0bio3fDAGqhvKrRcrjSiGdbtJ6jwrHhLvKtGTtBcHBbKl84ZiG7011nMGkHdcQ/Jawng4Faohct6
ofcKhhr9yDS6G+FFnaD7og9UULo/ha/tdCqtXJREO5qoWpsrZWk9R4Vhwl3lSFijUdVauJh9woI3oGmc
rZxDqoZlzWqV8vas/ZBz5c45clUUTxCpCa3PjyujisOGqq3W4qSVO6+gyX9SMZqurdpPUeFY9XeURN2H
Z8IstCI8JrGZbwtivRSalVIm8AocAhTeqKTmqCikcclr1fdEqIgo8lqm+qh4AK1SZWkE8R4Vj1d5XNEl
GNQckTIKMmso65CDmgNdMOhVJJVAjQz8AgLDvUolw1iZF9FzUomEMQwtUQQhCw4fdapWk9R4ViebvK8r
CRRQEU8DKFnI53x8FKqz/UGF0XYGipQbyUb+KwHaFeg4rFBHVUTmgyW0UEapVHSs4X9lldpPUeFY9XeV
QIwq3EgLK7Kqrn8EISLsWdEfK4EIPe0AZZyjVuHhnNaJoxBvSKItsjDMVKzA/wAow4b1OIOAGR3lfuRM
5DcnNaChSqyK0jqPCsurvKrKyu2YVV91mqj7qgVUBFVkLslhRDYTQDkqorFhAIQJ4XkKVRb1RaR1HhWX
V3m48UfgIhaqqEUOEKt1Ueaos1/dVAQUXyqlSVvWa0nqPCbY2QssLeIWzYdq2bDtWzYdq2bDtWxYdq2b
DtWxY9q2LHtWzYdq2bDtWzYdqoyw7Vs2Hatmw7Vs2Patmw7Vs2Hatmx7Vs2Hatmw7Vs2Hatmw7Vs2Hat
mw7VDm2Patiw7Vs2Hatiw7U+2tIxOzhf/8QAJhABAAICAgICAgMBAQEAAAAAAQARITFBUWFxkdGBobHB
8PEQ4f/aAAgBAQABPyEEdqmpAMWZoMw6FuVkldkYG5XFwSEY26PxPI0wUOL3IqjDmS5Gez6mowmI6I5d
wTeB5jsYwGq6/wDK7qlSPEqZ4h7p2NHt/wDY5JrlLrOEbrBlsUimIzOCTmQFTNVhj0GXFQRmr5lQOOhG
lLx0l7w/E4tG34m8sNpPWvc91K5Og5hl+JAn9EExWNn+pwq6yH4YtS4VY/x1CEfabGJiWLs8S2oa2xxz
TiiZQXrygLsW4oxGmydkA7nM6/wiKW01q+zuYFLN6MncRBwTSE9wCZQu4AqtdcDMA05qEYV8jDVtbUXM
1k7YlXYL9+CBAZ1xdXn3ubU/8914PMAzmDPV/ZAP3sGyUegqclnuonBNrQjan+QtjTUA5/qlYL+564ij
E/8AkS8UFVP1v8IFHRuhvkx4hbbtuHJHlEHNf0Syxflww2i1bc1UIIOY5ICVmhZOZkwTDzEapzldwMTY
0uYiU1/xiaymk8zl9Su7JqGDfqCL8I4zErXLWn4YeGtPcZAbDK6VTw9DRPRlYOZuclViffsnvDyQOs/T
/wAI+P8A7JjJ0eYrvdNQwdvM3ja98Sxk+0wRCFlHUK5LNszg79PzLAVefUJpbTtTEXMBG+o5AKte3mfJ
4lcxvRfJx/5bTYfpLIQugmDiX6Auf/LOVa5qFgz7OnqoIWOGuJuJ0pchC0/4xGzp+J+p/hC92/acJm4L
QcQZXxLfumAfUsHJxKIELMMxiPitn5iPZT8kflovMeLISrml+jAPKupV5WGWvOpThHWR+4ojhtwiJHiZ
B2PzM0H4P6QXiYT6hBC0HSBxo0X0VBi16g4/mP8AEZUnUMWai8T9pYZhwMf73SWvnFAe0AsAZtVHqvYc
wOIsjdzFMfy+iNFl0VaOeY81aLys9y1Lz35mPLsZrDEQQqCl9ovTZ+T29soWvswEnrk78P1EVyBZ2J0x
YPYMx9v6TF/JLj8qw15fywuLpOxsmoH+luPuHf8AqWYfFMQc3fwXKYFdZluuZlpC+J+h/hAMtbJxAuYm
Afc5hfDgIEC3yzvxM2PIFWPnShaOKTkeXuHKXvh5RYM/5Mym5TPglVHUF5RsAoBSWEvanx9n9zxxK9KY
nitldcuYG5lDvywvW3ViF8XMIuyMHGx8kXoCBGunFu6/iNwUcdL9/UrzLZDb2RFHgcv9TNJryzKsj1cT
/c6wXc30POLBs0jCVMhkYhs22otBWsln0goAruLKoQZeZQHpMd0TkCJl8UypTz/RL8j8dRyLhUCb0REr
+bKJajqZXdjol07T+EFU1Yn6jW4aotQ9rW+NH8ErMYExBNTSfCXcsZyseeoBWDoarzfMY3+0x9/BEcA/
3iY7/J6x/wCznAKpFrmOAGowTVv1iGY0fO4KbCFQx6lLOUJWvc4ZtIUcuIcJMGyi9nEJ0PpDZhsfENQ9
Ny85Pl2cQmU/JUaItjzklSjhkH2TIas0cQrrbzeWIoWvJ5gbrmzrq7a+ouAl6dc/TqJzHxFYqrwfhHVW
/wCxG1oJ3LnDZcCS/mYNtvJWawf4Zin1LI5a8jlA+KhmgzHu4PxAxi9KpZvy8Y4magnfOZRiHUT1UV5h
aLqutzIJV8ynZKC2w7IkrgqyGVRHqo3YA60ShdD+JgGp1q4+Aue7zFHY8EiA5Wc3f9SUsFdD3gNOFRN6
0P8Aj7mFyfgSxV/IJlHWxNMIo90GrSzruXhKwxKqelOa7YIGaN5VonTLehPyiiz4C/MSjSkZm25xiVC7
lBuRWnKoqYIyQaw+7hv2X/5HVYd+j9wGEDjHMeyNBmO07h13YDKygwnMvBpXPM/wOs5ByfKWI8xPIYm6
K+3f+ZgqdNKgvxUsAo2vY9lBpmTH8kWKHim57HxL3S5ot+UotZWceSDLoTotMIniOROiWsUQ8qOobA53
Q/qaMNE5kvlLXxvnxMg4Hjl8kwafVVOIZ5ZhxDYviY0S++yxD+C3LGQLDKMrAFJczi1NmIqxLqskxv8A
9CElQ2ZrnO3ObXkgO3ieGIDUu/Zd0w5+DNeeP3EDySx4B/UI9RP6ilm1tnDe8R2AplxN82rd8Sqg7inL
wKsbLO4JbcAO02Ie9PiXF2UEXNzx4ZvTL21ZmOPcY24A31CcAYIDAt74gFC2mtMrkgUAYdyxG1qS4I0G
kv8AOY7c1/Uhhfma3lqbp+Zg7oRGwHwx7PQcyPQm7CnI4MTjpF3uorXiVQWe5omRtu2X1looeJmsfmK/
Op2LCPqA24crn2jZRe7X/wDII1WUrIkr115gt6zkYMVE4Fb1G6McefmA3ZEQIaoWckW4PA6jGI2Kz81H
jnbTFmUPTuf7XSXO3wPzlDQsc5TXXZwTHXlJ+ap2sf8ACTUrNPGOYyfkOT8TKDcHLviN8J1/8lHHwS7p
6BPnPaveeYOTHm5WZRX+8dRwJv8AP1CRsrTwhu1LFBpYeSKdJfFO45fYTN+RWozOiGe5RcOZbaFrGdzd
Cun1Nh/GYwC4WZ2X/Ez/AN2EYYL+zKQNc1M7f/xmxWdZbRYgatz+Uqzhybg21ugqo/M3IZ8KQ3FOMRgh
C1pI13YNSs8nkE5SzicMh1vsdytBWqdmyEW9uFf4gXT6lOVsSwJezDOcV5amAsruXMTA5PMAmrnTc0No
2MqR81xG2xs+MK/6M5moa6QjLDcFq8dMzL3bEjuwtIrw6sW/yQHVItL7JQt7Fgj0nsiVboTBXbzPcpA1
xfM9cdQhy4BwQtlniKLtk64jnJzFJ1ZcwnacljLXQXZ1HQKDFsUCJoNv/n14oztal3ge+niZkl87go9f
xJSmzMi9je3iGuUxmKwPDAHSu4Qr8HmafgULnA+8EQPuCYLYlrx4uIpMrgGYBTfZDpfLhxExSojtrmHS
F2+ImFab68zDwrCIqGXCKKYMP2HggMAelQacjlhrRFqNPUVruI8RB36l5YDzHaWQ2Dbu8xN0iB1P8bpG
D/6vEdDCx3W6gPN5cVKqnP8AMFHtiWMW6jLoMR922AIZ2cx8JMrXvHMzTnHMSsExVaTJS7/iLZPAzEBp
rymODoQRbqmxMinNcENeBYBLGg7Ws+XolABodnfjKH7XoJkYhlZRlL5f7McQTQsp4Lx+X4xLseKoPZRj
v9eZa1sacDgiEgoZNEOe9N+ZUNRzcVua/ozK81/JlFa1XjEv1T9xrKXwSvWwM1NK+Ykv2zKbpb4g1vQj
j5+5Qgv3E8FMtYzeZfvmWAMpmZNZU4jTWrKRxoHpzNGndxLZZUZUGpUdwseUYHawyVcDK1LG13EU3p3i
f4ZhQW+Zh/sxmjf/AExrKYb54QMlYjol0xzJ1UpJruDSuoVQ2iYDwjLw0TDW8KT7vmWLq6hTQrcwxjaW
cVnFT2fETh123OmPcotKg3hZH4uN4MsB5uYrzDWLhoVz1E7tINtXxFa/6pEcmUvXLfcA18n7iu/k/cAw
X5/cUri8/ueM9P7gZWL3+4hZ877gevlfcW+79xYpq9/uK7+b9wAAPf7mX+79z/pfuLlfvfc03zfuKGfk
/cU3877n/S/co+79z/pfuBNnzfuBfZ+5/wBT9xQme/3BlFHv9xejV7/cB18/7hFl7po1U//aAAwDAQAC
AAMAAAAQ1bMCOAMQDBYgLL9OKFNAEEKPY4xrd5qPHwgdoTR9yc3r+YuMattf48u5omVkFe6kXTVQhQpk
JmZZxsrK+IPpjQpz7I4fmokInyr4vF4o+94macLcotIPZ+q2Af8AAr4rApteheO0o8bElnPglpYARlqO
I+PiK6PTWVlJEK/4www/3/3wYQYfQf/EACcRAQACAgEDAwQDAQAAAAAAAAEAESExQRBRYXGx8IGRwdEg
ofHh/9oACAEDAQE/EJUqASj1bMVfVJCYjCMJUCPw4hN4fmY0Rlx6HEuJkjF1RWm2DW6loVsoRmMEZBYT
HGvnEOMHl16YimVbbi8/qKi4l5bqFv4dyly5jcMo1ABUBJR6QrDWLg7IK/PmeSNeb5YmxdaL2zVnXD+J
oJcEsDwzJOzD6zBc8qwqSIrlv0g3O0TBGZGi9whNvGbxAKhKlgMXDQJxKCuIB9kdRHvbR9MPeGFbf64j
QOT2jfbj8QkYHBTdeuPa5e4VDfs+YmkVEonoOYuQXztUQV4jZe0rKRc8wLr/ABHAbYiGMdo3DLzAi0D8
uE257P3FeRekup4RH/ZXHv5/kV+yXtfPWDig5HeZeDFYJgNhEpxJRtqX2AluWL0myo1h8faFUXFQ1ITi
w7H3h7UvWflMSjZVHDj9Q3b7PWOW29FgY7ijDfvd/HmZITLGNb3DGsJ3EdqiC+pOJO4iuVjaMwdGRTBE
MFZZL+ty2V4dClEhhmsS+hdQWX1mCU6l0imWgorXRf4vRcuWy0tlstlu8tlstlstlsuf/8QAHxEAAwAD
AQEAAwEAAAAAAAAAAAERECExQVEgYXEw/9oACAECAQE/EPwWWiEr/wAKdZLYvo6eWfMcW2P4F9idwz4J
qPzBs0mNSghdP4bfRBhoLuFQGyNEeHAhKVpn0hdOFEMm8N6N5KbRoljEGrsTUjIIbI6mJoX3BKJ6xLwh
PZ0g3hKJEjhxijY5tSsLGMuD6XY/1iwWwoF6NuES2xgl6TF4KcxpREIUiR1DBtLWOvWKQvga8EgnRVj9
WxU3osf2b8KuzYCVVigRRCMcTdNEGm2j1Jopj2d2NCb2SjTFmGzGjFIkwgSF8xKfzGxcF0iIiIgiIIiI
mJ+P/8QAJhABAAICAgICAwADAQEAAAAAAQARITFBUWFxgZGhscHR4fDxEP/aAAgBAQABPxAbdfykDA1o
iajVQwPzeIKrt9FfmJAdc/74bFNGP98oMBXX++AqAO/88CLV2G1/MYlRW/8AfDzZl1kfmChhHCt/cUWH
an/Ym2brP+44AOAr+4gRTwSvbcBZzTTF+7iwXv8A1uN2VgaP7KYoPH+yVirAvH43Eyhezw135hSKF/H+
Yk2FrefzuLH6tn1cM/MWtR9y0CDSz/mPlj5fzMpeX4fzAXrfNP7i0jssOw5crNkDffvBCnC61EGWt2kN
oEEyD+YhQnkdjGBSOwtikBpdKIs3SQ2PNf1lMkFvh3pmdarulo9/uU0m2zR+VRHg4vPXqHcGLd2nXRiv
zgyeBtLwfMQTsDJ3n8A+4RpnUR5F0Js9RKEHYUvDlKSCP7QRR7/p9IMI1JbpElCzns2szHVQOjxACKp5
PUxe+Qm79wGIVMluuYR4LNXMDzMUcQxurK9RJCyriuI4aNW6li9bPO7bRW94apQQR0lipJgL3FXHJbpj
+xKtVqIAwuhF13UyRZsw9/6j9OBZQdq/ojUNXwDiuTuNLHJSyCsFUqbou4k1NF6RVU5BzxOxWglEQWUo
cM4d8nZiO0ehEbEdI8nmV7KYBdPfsZPhb9LAErcO1vnlDvpHJyQ0ATyJ709y160FMNx1SMkSyHhPkLC8
DHY8OD8XLXAul3Xt9y+DqAu3hXZ8XcC3LGkXcFVte4wDRjm//h8lUjvLebYhZBpEkeoJeYL4xAeZYANb
v/ZE6VfAiz3E06YAHQ1dwunHCotxZDIoHhwBq4JhggsNEzxD1XIAW+8S4GyuL3HGLS7CGvi17XqGyqYK
AE1zDi+34c9y+KE2RudJh2sJ9XHDI2uzhlxyI2JshOAptW0N8VA9NPcukLsvD3EOoobborY8Y8uo43SP
pDg9EKDkTxLnO4VRXBI9lhK1oH+VyeoinGpkvzCHRTT/APF4AopFbqQZzVnjniU5oYNIvk8eYlNiRjhx
uOXs8OGPMYbO4NE4hY3AuajGrE/bcst6shaee3PuEFbqz0uEiuESzxUHQxmUAuodndNS0PtYWVKWQGF/
kXKpdpdbO+R/H4lTYZiv5IXyx+EhO6qI0u483b/Yd6ONE8qAx55uV70G5klBc7qZhRgGEPs/cJ692cnm
JgLHAmmXLpxGhgZp0V8qPSdQKKq5FX3FbjueRttKKvErZbngg4z5z8TZo0PzRGGMFW8259QPt7vWKPcX
kXhDTmuKjJ6GmRaw0p3ww+mxYPg3rOZR8sXR3XPxCrBpWtzZQ7K9NkMuV7n2wOvER6lCgKIU0rVYYO8G
Y3XeiD6GLMSsqWdYxQwxqVTLCkb48Pw0/EdYlU1CAf8A1/0gMBvBCRkDT4K/kz3Us+BcTh/UcOxYqqdj
zh+pUQKG4tYwLtezncNHC1caU/bWH4h3BdkIipUXfcyrCBwuh+G/iVYiuBU9Tq1wTs1dvQskNc1KAfbH
iReW6FKD6IykOqyDevJZtiUBlCqLg+bX6hHmFwSENqoGrxGS+oDQD8m8HqOuXQU5U0Q1C+SqENjw4fHZ
KotGpb+CUicIkZWnYSr+YP8AyD1G4LD3WvmUrHpjA3wXU9vk7eOqYdyrEqJpGZbWZVX/ADIP9gvxhfwP
8yiKqH24/NRkKUFhQHaupdp2aQ+wqBTzCb2CddREwqITvwh09J4xA5lrRQu+NPMpGsKywc1TRX1E7A0L
X7qj5qC53X0Tv/crCOCnkZmQUk8qVjFiqnotAqDVqLyKWlV8tf8AcShWBSlDWSsnzK7HPZMtRcRGwllu
1uDNfEbeJ9gFcvqUzrB2Kq9FfiXNY7opqrDgOIyVZN6HFHhTZLCQrqKah4P6wHYAsbRpT8fcMRvSBYWy
vWR4jdRqDRZafdxAKSo6CwPlfr/y7memibuVFcmP4I6116i5/VQWaDRvw8HwZj5JVZoX/HolNRvQIEZ+
X6jDbIJbbB1zDyeGpbwpRUTnD3GCFoAE8FLdTAoN47bd7vyweYbXI2ngS0Tw+oytbcgDvyJuBlU29Ac8
TPCVGMg2S5fd5rKYsFS1QXe29/yVfZFE/wDImALZYlr2+L3E2wk1rPEueYMEcNZwycMK2xrKr3dfMQgI
C2Nnnmii/EAZVIXvH9h1TAX7gBuA23xGrbbvcvvn+RrmGClJ45H1EO4DB0aCE5jnlgElAMpdJ9XEVc2T
WcX8QzmUV4AP3/ZjkurcvfojZVa57bf7maOwvFo/stVgckCrhpzmMALnGgmDwAeWJp8CfNGI1dtBSpLf
fnxMW0+BPFTfDOJTzQSBQtsbWarMWsaMZb8wA6UKauvPvUBXNascioEbkeZ5ZWNLwH4IV7FB0d0xq0Oy
5VW+Ih4yANFASugYbwB/LJb6KtslAYdDEqlRiDti0C3i008MU0GFYB8yohvKlnhSUZFpNDlfcwUYNhK9
jMqBXmBwMosIzkU89wBBYmubRrPn/rjh55T9QGiGXLI1+VMn1HNkc0ZrxM2UwOT7ipwmqD3BI5qNoFtd
x/gJwU6YyeZAlf09RQWKp8hh/QLh5wA4/kJ8SLT0/wBfULpdpmfqZ1XVuOOKI3p9yDmxgfmOSmfnMHCg
0qnXA/cKdMj0C/HiOFUFVcfdzHMey/2Ljr4JjiqIaUA2TD89zneVTvOA9xBKqLwPAbf+uMdJXehe4gFX
ZSK7xxEGKOb+RzBfLeL2af1KseQF3FqFenitQxsGS0Ht0SpWNNh+TE7ei2lOPH+YSV59n+4F5ECo5SDd
ko+IFaJYJozb1HoNkcoBbzV/MPmZSyILV2OptVrsa7/UwIC27gQ+wmgXSHTJHkAszzfmX0itAzyXgDaH
XQ81+1FfolVZeB9wWfTDEDHZD2PJBukgIDf8EeqQcq9IYg0kXgz+NTELB5WBcZ2N+viK6pMpAu8GOInt
ig1WmX7zLbdgmkOaZ+CHH0D5/W4wwFQgagvOF57mLdB6Qs/K4vqMQwzxhbOtaIpTgQCUkWgy8UtksiWl
b2jGgXXQe+YhBVULV6aMj51KBbUm4Hnv1FkgFLHqXTWBsZ9QxxNAf4zK4tSayUEWBaYs7xGw48PI/JqK
9QC7pl+1+CdjgQDYMmu4PQd/NqHI/e4Spy15NDw6f9Sli06Ter9zWyzq6wZfyQpiCyfLTX7mEHZH5Gka
Uf8AcCtM3SudZPIktiUWz9Ax+CZIjFXojQUGXdxDUrIA0bdc3B3QKIqwxYdVFeyDlWSt0cyluDgOLzFi
AwaQgFYSdsj24L9stRZoGjwQQUaDQ9viIAULLM1di0MuSh7Pg3NzNBZw9x+JTsu7j4HkHfmXCkpOEYNt
mCFFklk6oI9tHZ9zBKgUopxSi3H2ZWrPoT8wRINADZYS9qZwlPiUoq/NN6HZp9y1jWQZmqqiLpQzQIdu
jK/UObiKG3GhycZeNRVwLSkVVpxe/iXVSWKgDleoRZVuCHvL+JW/Gql9gdLTycwEgihooDzm19QgVDKc
r0AfxC0IV7oC/wBxkBvb8g/p8+JnUMmHs3ZKiiCstlSwsOODJuWA2HAePMuiBa4K7e2UHU0/iDRKSoc7
zCAwqgKFjM5NHL5jcGcLCcJD2sF5TFVbRafzAslkLmwqBEWTABKk29oxAFjW/kwj/hnm9twfWa+ILQRh
Gm9vAcstD2U4OrNk4GaR8FfyXGJppZcJW9/VxLvgFwYYfks1NcVVlJ1fHwQnW9dpV08OBl0/ZFSwmlrf
crppF0tO13x9aqOyWoI8BX8hU8KarOjGHxCyAERorEwnqYtUzTdmoyAAi6R1+WMDJM74uK1B0BbfiMKg
dDYeTl/EcNKNBXHqEQtFx8Qi/BLcdrU28eINUHDRD/MvQ2xZn3LqjGNTHIXZ+piI1NIDxFa1V4JqwQtC
72QqqGW9J/maLgTIFoat8x8hNNq9AnsuZdBCI2NgoNiDFoFseDSvTKY7JTIfaDyZFfn5gAe8CspeWLqn
8RVdXQofaxDXt7VX8REgx1+lJXazbJQxTSzdPB5iipohcrRjm2FYgWnYthX4ryRMSPBSnvtT8TCPfKz2
c5M+iNmxTgi5QKJyQIeUp+IsyFax7Wdc+I2ZXLQHR1Lm4xh/klYVou26mgZ5HFQcwctMx+3Lfw1KxzdT
WfKNJNi6LZ8wynuZQwyOauxbd08eohIIOB4mRpTSrqF5dczH6gEcMOvkijk+FCeEwPuMnAWOTONH1FHy
8yFGbvky4mL++QjYqvUXMpsA2/8AkAuy3ZH1iZ56LNQoNNQEhuAT3Y8xgNFA3kdryxMRKgLy059d38Sn
gyWbozHNqV1jjiMmAMr9Of8AMVMhHIQx/wBiZoqZhOQPUQVu+AlNTPSGgtP3GBMVyr/UqFWaVGUGCiN9
/H+4UNsmLeE5ZVgA1uY3XcSmItM7NVURgFyCtc1qITUWUF/Eq8uqauNBmz1ZcC2UNbV5YtcnBIDK2gav
axwpA2z0LsuYHnMqFRr53CchgsBOE2PUPkYGjg4GWbacL6Db+JtqXDms9QJCFQb4g4YuIVeHXmMT4acD
wynAAAu2KxM8iaL9ks2JcuiNdgsutopi5+UexTXqVYQZxjzK6DgPcS4NGFvjx1DrM6D4Yzn5liMEpH2w
UYUvHxfUfgAtW2twTdyzlc3EIsNJlZZeTjmAR6jwfniCC2AHudQ2IFF84aeDV3S6D1Fso5cPPiZuFw7r
50yswNjlovfzDgiSaWgSNUIVhAdZi2qAosB+JgCtqmsgGJgxrg5PIx4XfTP+JeWubK+zUGA00W+9Q3ua
xXD4NXFPAcrylUIudoGmnq4TaLA8BiXg5qDgeYrJQwADtFAOLXeC2W/uosNKXXGual7Dn6Q8HmMFivNQ
i4uks4suplCREYpoS+ZaqAhVGmmn7+oPXNFrDjNeYsUW0rbfcpKEV2PcBqMqlD3OM2bJoisjawZhRv0k
cbG1KF8fUvCbZos/USmGVUflN6oo8w79EHmMKg6oeIwRE2B8sxGpZWfi4pWLYDVluo1+1Co2hNOzk4J4
gBuqThvZFSGxof8AmVe4MNaRvIS0g5x4ityjFvpfUCkg3NPh/wC3Audq6HDgJWiryrqVYLeGkBWQuXa1
izaB63VjXQAIlCzSBisIeZ1lu5feRZqRU17YtLGLq24ALXyM2CmC1lgceUthTcJ2sO5Hmgte13EEuI6O
eh1DCciDEdWmQcwt0MRAGwRaYIVBmMarXEzAbGFyj+tyv3E2ARZTq+I2mgxa4jDQq2hxANIqQW31MoQC
7t8/5lgCHCYX+IEChya4/wATEgPFOOZXBcq5fVQxddiondHOS/EBViAWBfcP6BFK7wOIM5doCvDuLbOf
weGFAAAFuJlFK3Y5rhrF7zAhDU0cxIuwCOcfybADtY4xoFK+NxXxJd1dxWwrRy1mXHDQMoX8wQ8eBNDC
hassqKu2FqxDoRvGWPQ1NBUTvPPqMxSkBozBAQo+938T7THN9xxbjwmbTKbZu9spOF8JYSgXmnFf6lis
VBnlmVUMsbXO/wBwyo40qzXPtlFIW1eZWWqobyPSM2WS2ujnMvIy3WaCi+4ApUsKrR8rA2F0x/wzKK2w
2YP6zGgi52ZiiBtQ0TLB4tNQAF2xCsi07I4gJFmXEGmGZ0mEY7cK1MU+WK/pCEbFJrFZd5loOXqUVKpT
aRLRDLvEKSciyNS6sdGXpuOmN+KuHLcmtG50LWdRnqIjULd2tRkkmglWTkdx46a5UCId0dyIV6xLWqUo
mT7nB5PcJrHivFILYXFFEoAlbuOwq57aQGzqlQjdlMi6gUEYBulVxSAUK1UouLAooBRbWAn/2Q=="}}
```

from this when i am trying to acess only pic field to save it on mongodb i am getting [object object]

```
user.pic=req.body.pic;

user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                req.login(user, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(400).send(err);
                    } else {
                        res.jsonp(user);
                        console.log('userrrrrrrdd'+user);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

how to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

your pic field is containg a file object. So it is showing you like **[object object]**

If you want to access filename from this pic object then you can write **"pic.filename"**, same way if you want to  access those file content then you can write **"pic.base64"**, this wil show your image.

Comment: i tried it but getting conplict when i try to updated other fields because second time of updation also i need all the fiels of pic mainly base64